# Can't find the error in my approach to solve a work problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, energy, work, power

The question is:

> A box of 5 kg, initially at rest is being pushed by a boy with a constant force of 20N. The constant frictional force acting between the box and the floor is 5N. Find the power developed by the boy at that instant when the displacement of the box is 216 m.

I chose to answer it in two different ways:

**First approach:**

Net force acting on box$=Force By Boy  - Friction$
$$=(20-5)N$$
$$=15N$$

Now, $$a= \frac Fm$$
$$= \frac {15} {5} m/s²$$
$$=3 m/s²$$

Now,
$$v²=u²+2aS$$

Given, $S=216m$

Hence, since initial velocity is 0,
$$v²=2 × 3 × 216$$
$$=1296$$

Therefore, $v=36 m/s$

Therefore power developed by boy= $Fv$
$$=(20 × 36)W$$
$$=720 W$$

**Second Approach:**

Net force acting on box$=Force By Boy  - Friction$
$$=(20-5)N$$
$$=15N$$

Now, $$a= \frac Fm$$
$$= \frac {15} {5} m/s²$$
$$=3 m/s²$$

Given, displacement $S=216 m$

Also, work done by boy $=F × S$
$$=(20 × 216)J$$
$$=4320 J$$

Now,
$$S= ut + 0.5at²$$
or, $$216=0.5 × 3 × t²$$

Therefore, $t=12 s$

Hence, power developed by boy $$=\frac Wt$$
$$= \frac {4320}{12} W$$
$$= 360 W$$

As you can see, the answer is different for different approaches. How is that possible? Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the first method answers the specific question asked.

In your first method, you examine the conditions at the moment the box passes the $216$ metre mark.  You find the velocity at that moment and multiply by the constant force to determine the *instantaneous* power at that moment/location, as you are explicitly asked.

In your second method, you correctly calculate the total energy transferred by the boy to the box and floor during the entire $12$ second, $216$ m push. You then assume (incorrectly) that this energy is transferred uniformly over the $12$ second exercise, divide by the time, and produce the *average* power output.

The right answer, but not to the question asked.

Comment: Ok but isn't W/t equal to Fv? The time taken by the box to acquire that velocity in the first case was 12 s, as we have a constant acceleration. And $W/t$ is literally equal to $Fv$, just some quantities have been changed. So why are they different?

Comment: No; W/t = force times average velocity

Comment: Alright I get it, $W/t = W × (S/t)$ where $S/t$ gives average velocity, and we need the instantaneous one that's why we use the equation of motion. Thank you.